# detect when the application is no longer active

Tags: android

I need to terminate my background threads when the app is terminated. What is the least-convoluted way to accomplish this?

All i can think of is to keep track of the number of running activities, by having each activity report onCreate and onDestory events to Application and when the number reaches zero, assume the app is terminated?!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making your background threads run as a Service or Services.  Then you can bind these to each activity and unbind them when the activity ends.  When the last activity is unbound from the service, the service will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry edited this because I didn't realize my answer is only applicable in an emulated environment. You might be able to use [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29) but I am not sure.

Comment: have you actually read what the docs say for onTerminate() ??

Comment: Yeah my bad, I had never used it just knew that the function existed.

Comment: Yes, you might be able to use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` (can't say for sure since there's no actual description of it in the javadocs) in two or three years when most devices are running API lvl 14.. :(  In the meantime, reference-counting your Activities is probably the safest plan.

Answer (score 0):

When an app is terminated in Android the entire Unix process is killed, so all of your background threads will stop at that time.